# Using a style sheet for modern browsers and another for older browsers

Tags: css

This isn't about using IE conditionals, here is my problem

I have a fixed width site, I'm using 960 grid and I like this, and it works in most browsers including ie8 and ie7.

Now I like that old browsers like ie7 ie8 and use the **960 file fixed width** and default style.css wordpress and modern browsers use the **fluid version of 960 grid**.

**Summarizing**

a) In old browsers load fixed width 960.
b) In modern browsers use the fluid version of 960 responsive to the site.

Modern browsers can be detected and used a style sheet for them and in older browsers another style sheet?

Is there any function in wordpress that allows loading a stylesheet if the browser is modern, and load another stylesheet if the browser is old?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_check_browser_version()`.

It will return False on failure, array of browser data on success. Then Checking the browser data you can assign particular CSS stylesheet to particular browser.

[Reference »](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_browser_version)

Comment: This function is engineered for admin (relatively low amount of users/browsers) and works via remote POST request to API. Highly not recommended to run in front end for every visit.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
What could be better solution to this case?

I'm complicating things more than they should?

Answer (score 0):

WP performs some limited browser sniffing on load, there are `$is_winIE` and `$is_macIE` globals set when browser is detected as Internet Explorer. It doesn't detect versions however.

This seems precisely like a case for using IE conditionals.